How to prevent installing apps in private space in android 15 beta?
In new private space feature in Android 15 devices, No Push notifications are showing.
In my app, push notification is mandatory to the user, and installing app in private space won't show any push notifications. Hence, I want to prevent the app from installing on the private space.
Thanks in advance!
